# hamburger icon is not showing up even if I call componentHandler.upgradeDom();

Tags: material-design-lite

```
<header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="mdl-navigation">
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link is-active" href="/">link</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link is-active" href="/">link</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link is-active" href="/">link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link is-active" href="/">link</a>
    </nav>
</div>

<!-- Colored FAB button with ripple -->
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored">
    <i class="material-icons">add</i>
</button>
```

According to http://mdlhut.com/2015/07/where-is-the-mdl-drawer-icon/ it should work as long as I call `componentHandler.upgradeDom()` after I dynamically load the html. Just to make sure I'm calling the upgradeDom correct I added the button to see if the ripple effect is added. And the button is updated but the hamburger icon is not appearing.

If I inline the html the hamburger icon appears.

Comment: Did you see if it has perhaps a wrong css styling like color white?

Comment: Calling upgradeDom() sounds like a hack. What is the real solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dynamically load the html, you should run the following inside your init function after the `DOM` is load. Notice that the `setInterval` function to ensure `DOM` has enough time to load before executing the `componentHandler` method

jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      setInterval(function() {
           componentHandler.upgradeAllRegisteredElements();
      }, 1000);
 });
```

DOM API

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      setInterval(function() {
           componentHandler.upgradeAllRegisteredElements();
      }, 1000);
 });
```

Comment: Hi, already tried with setInterval and dom ready. The button is upgraded so somehow I think it works. I just don't know why the hamburger icon is not appearing.